# php form refresh send form again (prevent)

Tags: javascript

when a form is filled and send, if you refresh the page, its says that the form will send again. (submit the form again).

What is a good way to prevent this from happening? or kill this session?

any guidance in this?

thank you

Comment: This is not a javascript problem, but php ;)

Comment: @Xavinou this is not PHP problem, but HTTP Request ;)

Comment: Why cant u use the Clear property of the controls when ever the click happens on the send button, after sending the form.

Answer (score 3):

After processing the POST informations, do a

```
header('Location: your_url');
exit();
```

Comment: I vote for this solution, but sometimes its hard to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX to send POST variables to server, so refreshing browser window problem will not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep displaying the form there is no reason to prevent this.

Otherwise - i.e. after the form has been submitted successfully - store any messages you need to display in your session and then redirect to whatever page you want to display. This ensures the user is moved away from the POSTed page.